# How can I insert data from multiple Access rows into a single, multi-lined string in Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I am trying to get data from a result set into my java application so that I can display it to the user. Something I'd like to implement is a partial search function that displays multiple rows of data based on an input string. If that string appears in any serial number in the database, it pulls that entire row and adds it to a string.

res is the ResultSet

```
public String searchToString() {
    String temp = "";
    
    try {
        while(res.next()) {
            temp = res.getString("ProductCode") + "        " + res.getString("SerialNum") + "        "
            + res.getString("DateSold") + "        " + res.getString("SoldTo") + "        " + res.getString("Notes") + "\n"; 
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println(se);
    }
    
    return temp;
}
```

I have tried changing the queries I use and figured out that the LIKE query was the best one. However, if I try outputting the string to a text area I only see one output where many more are supposed to be. I am definitely missing something from my code to tell it to continue adding the rest of the rows to the string, but I haven't come across anything on the Internet that can tell me what it is.

Comment: You are overwriting `temp` in each iteration of your while loop. Change `temp = ...` to `temp += ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting temp

//try +=

```
temp += res.getString("ProductCode") + "        " + res.getString("SerialNum") + "        "
            + res.getString("DateSold") + "        " + res.getString("SoldTo") + "        " + res.getString("Notes") + "\n"; 
        }
```

//or temp = temp +

```
temp = temp + res.getString("ProductCode") + "        " + res.getString("SerialNum") + "        "
                + res.getString("DateSold") + "        " + res.getString("SoldTo") + "        " + res.getString("Notes") + "\n"; 
            }
```